# How to parcel cascading classes with Parceler?

Tags: parceler

I can parcel some models using Parceler like this:

```
@Parcel(Serialization.BEAN)
public class PasswordSetModel {

    private String mPassword;
    private String mRepetition;

    /* Getter & Setter */
    ...
```

But if this class is part of another class, the mechanism does not work. I am getting an NPE for mPasswordSetModel. Creating an instance in an constructor did not work, because the members mPassword and mRepetition were null after unparcelling.

```
@Parcel
public class RegistrationModel {

    private PasswordSetModel mPasswordSetModel;

    /* Getter & Setter */
    ...
```

So how can I parcel this using Parceler?

Answer (score 1):

okay, the problem was that I uses "wrong" setter methods. In order to use fluent interface style I made it this way:

```
public String getPassword() {
    return mPassword;
}

public PasswordSetModel setPassword(String password) {
    mPassword = password;
    return this;
}

public String getRepetition() {
    return mRepetition;
}

public PasswordSetModel setRepetition(String repetition) {
    mRepetition = repetition;
    return this;
}
```

It seems that the setters were now found and therefor the model was NULL